# sed regex match non-whitespace or tab

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I am trying to parse input that looks like this:

```
i171_chr1_C_MSTA_K0.184_full    i266_chr1_+_MSTA_K0.195_full    92.06   2255    125 21  1   2221    2235    1   0.0 3123
i172_chr1_+_MLT1D_K0.575_full   i172_chr1_+_MLT1D_K0.575_full   100.00  2290    0   0   1   2290    1   2290    0.0 4229
i172_chr1_+_MLT1D_K0.575_full   i172_chr1_+_MLT1D_K0.575_full   100.00  2290    0   0   1   2290    1   2290    0.0 4229
```

Desired output is:

```
i171 1 i266 1 92
i172 1 i172 1 100
i172 1 i172 1 100
```

In another words, I am extracting name before first "_" to the first column and part after chr into second column (similiarly for third and fourth column).

I wrote command that works properly for first four columns:

```
grep -v "#" blastGE90_lengthGE1000 | cut -f 1,2 | sed -r 's/(.+)_chr([0-9XY]+)_.+\t(.+)_chr([0-9XY]+).+/\1 \2 \3 \4/'
```

However, when I try to match third column in input, I am not successful. I always match the last match instead of one I want:

```
grep -v "#" blastGE90_lengthGE1000 | cut -f 1,2 | sed -r 's/(.+)_chr([0-9XY]+)_.+\t(.+)_chr([0-9XY]+).+([0-9]+\.).+/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5/'
```

Therefore, I would like to use regexp to match non-whitespace or tabulator, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed your command:

```
grep -v "#" blastGE90_lengthGE1000 | cut -f 1-3 | sed -r 's/(.+)_chr([0-9XY]+)_.+\t(.+)_chr([0-9XY]+)_.+\t([0-9]+).+/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5/'
```

You need to use `cut -f 1-3` not `cut -f 1,2` because you need the first three columns.
I also fixed the last capture group in the `sed` expression.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk` here:

```
$ awk -F'_| +' '{gsub(/chr/,"");print $1,$2,$7,$8,int($13)}' file
i171 1 i266 1 92
i172 1 i172 1 100
i172 1 i172 1 100
```

Comment: Also working, thanks. Also thank you for the idea of multiple delimiters, will definitely use one day.